# How can I range with using LIKE query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am working on a searching system with pagination, and I am just confused while using my code,

```
SELECT * FROM musics WHERE name LIKE  '%".$query."%' AND id BETWEEN $start_from AND $end_to
```

But it is not working as expected, it results 0 rows; 
I want to use LIKE query with within the range, like **id** from 4-8.

Comment: Show a little bit more code. What values does $start_from and $end_to have? What is your table schema?

Comment: do you mean something like this? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4e77f/1

Comment: yea @john, that's what i was looking for, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

it may be a case issue
try to lowercase your arguments

```
SELECT * FROM musics WHERE lower(name) LIKE  lower('%" . $query . "%') AND id BETWEEN $start_from AND $end_to
```

also make sure that  *$start_from < $end_to*
the first argument you give to the 'BETWEEN' have to be smaller than the second argument

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
"SELECT * FROM musics WHERE name LIKE  '%$query%' AND id >= $start_from AND id <= $end_to"
```

and check your table too to make sure the matched data are exist.